# Does guava come with a command line argument parser

Tags: guava

Does gauva come with a command line parser in itself ? or should I resort to jcommander/args4j/apache cli or something else ?

Answer (score 11):

No, it does not. Use one of those libraries you mentioned. Or something else.

This is the [Guava User Guide](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained), use that (or Google search) next time you're looking for some major task solution and are not sure whether it's included or not.

For minor tasks and utility methods, you'll need to refer to the actual [JavaDocs](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/index.html).